# SelectListItem / updating application form MVC3 4.0 to MVC5 4.5.1 / view extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, selectlistitem

I used the following in my MVC3 (aspx)  .NETFramework 4.0 works great.

view page extension method:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDownListItems<T>(this ViewPage<T> viewPage, string listName, int? currentValue, bool addBlank)
        where T : class
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> pairs = viewPage.ViewData[listName] as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>;

        if (addBlank)
        {
            SelectListItem emptyItem = new SelectListItem();
            list.Add(emptyItem);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in pairs)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = pair.Value;
            item.Value = pair.Key.ToString();
            item.Selected = pair.Key == currentValue;
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Partial model:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> DoYouSmokeNowValues = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "Yes" },
            { 2, "No" },
            { 3, "Never" }
        };
        public static int MapDoYouSmokeNowValue (string value)
            {
            return (from v in DoYouSmokeNowValues
                    where v.Value == value
                    select v.Key).FirstOrDefault();
            }

        public static string MapDoYouSmokeNowValue (int? value)
            {
            return (from v in DoYouSmokeNowValues
                    where v.Key == value
                    select v.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        public string DoYouSmokeNow
            {
            get
                {
                return MapDoYouSmokeNowValue(DoYouSmokeNowID);
                }
            set
                {
                DoYouSmokeNowID = MapDoYouSmokeNowValue(value);
                }
            }
```

In the view:

```
  @Html.ExDropDownList("DoYouSmokeNowID", this.GetDropDownListItems("DoYouSmokeNowValues", this.Model.PersonalSocial.DoYouSmokeNowID, false), this.isReadOnly)
```

When I updated the application to MVC5 .NETFramework 4.5.1.  First I could not resolve GetDropDownListItems, so I copied it from the extension model to the view using @functions,  I get this error.

```
The type argument for method 'IEnumerable<SelectedItem>  ASP._Page_Views_Visit_PhysicalExam_cshtml.GetDropDownListItems<T>(ViewPage<T>, string,,int?,bool)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the the type arguments explicity.
```

One other thing, the MVC3 solution was one project, while MVC5 is multi layer and I have the models in the Domain layer, while the view extension is the project as the views.

My question is why I can't resolve the page view extension method?

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: `GetDropDownListItems` method expects 2 parameters `bool?, bool` but your passing three `string, bool?, bool`.

Comment: You are correct Stephen, I posted the wrong method.  I updated the question with more details regarding the view extension method.

Comment: Is the error message still the same? (it does not make sense). My question is what is all this supposed to be doing anyway, and whats `@Html.ExDropDownList()`? Seems like this could all be done in just a few lines of code making use of MVC's built in methods

Comment: The error message is not the same.  @html.ExDropDownList() is the html helper I am using.  The original project was developed in 2010 using linq-to-sql; now I am using EF 6.1.  I thought I will be easier just to update it rather than rewriting the whole program.  I use these methods in many views; also I have to keep the same database structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ViewPage` is a base class for **WebForms**-style views (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

**Razor** views use a different class, `WebViewPage` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg402107%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

So, without actually trying to recreate your helpers, I would guess that at a minimum you need to hang the extension method off of WebViewPage:

```
GetDropDownListItems<T>(this WebViewPage<T> viewPage, string listName, int? currentValue, bool addBlank)
```